# Access DICOM files via DICOMDIR using pydicom

Tags: python, pydicom

I am new to this file type. I want to access files in the folder `S65279_1148582599_LIVER__QIU__SHIFU__M_53` by accessing the DICOMDIR located besides that folder. Inside the folder, I want to access the "IMG" files in a folder that looks like:

```
IMGO00O0000 2021/12/22 8:55 13,408 KB
IMGOO000001 2021/12/2  8:55 13,840 KB
IMGO0000002 2021/12/22 8:54 8 KB
IMG00000035 2021/12/22 8:54 103 KB
IMGOO000739 2021/12/22 8:54 2 KB
Objects.xml 2021/12/22 8:54 11 KB
```

After reading the DICOMDIR file using `dcmread`, I get something like this:

```
(0004, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 232
(ee04, 1400) Offset of the Next Directory Record UL: e
(0004, 1410) Record In-use Flag                  US: 65535
(e004, 1420) Offset of Referenced Lower-Level Di UL: 0
(e004, 1430) Directory Record Type               CS: 'SR DOCUMENT'
(e004, 1500) Referenced File ID                  CS: ['S65279_1148582599_LIVER_QIU_SHIFU_M_53', 'IMGOOOR0739']
(0004, 1510) Referenced sOP Class UID in File    UI: Comprehensive SR Storage
(eee4, 1511) Referenced sOP Instance UID in File UI: 1.2.276.0.48.10201. 1.20110506073656578008
(0004, 1512) Referenced Transfer Syntax UID in F UI: Explicit VR Little Endian
(0008, 0e00) Group Length                        UL: 48
(0008, 0005) Specific Character Set              CS: 'IS0_IR 192'
(0008, 0023) Content Date                        DA: '20110322'
(e008, e033) Content Time                        TM: '095212'
(0020, e000) Group Length                        UL: 10
(ea20, 0013) Instance Number                     IS: '0'
```

How should I proceed to get 'IMG00000739'? I have tried tried to access `ReferenceFileID` using `ds[0x0004,0x1500]`, but this is not working.

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/tutorials/filesets.html). Also note that using image links to text is discouraged, use plain text instead - see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The documentation is the first thing I checked. However, I still do not know how to do it after I read the documentation. Hints are really appreciated.

Comment: Just to re-iterate from the documentation: DICOMDIR is just an index to the files. You can access each of the files directly by loading it using `dcmread`, you don't need to use DICOMDIR if you already know which files you want to access.

Comment: Yeah I know. But the thing is I am required to load only DICOMDIR and to access other files from DICOMDIR. I wonder if there is a way of doing it at all.

Comment: You have to read the other files directly, from DICOMDIR you can only get their filename (via `ReferencedFileID`).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really helpful to know that I have to access them directly. Just one final thing: do you mind giving me the syntax on how to access ReferencedFileID? If ```ds = dicom.dcmread(path)``` is the DICOMDIR, then ```ds.ReferencedFileID``` yields an error saying 'DicomDir' object has no such attribute although I am seeing it from the list of tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DICOMDIR file contains a linked list of directory records for patients, studies, series and images with some of their attributes. If all you need is a list of the DICOM files referenced in the DICOMDIR, you can just find all `ReferencedFileID` tags, which contain the path components to the path as a list. `ReferencedFileID` is only present in the image level directory records, so if you search for these entries, you will get the path to all contained DICOM images.

In `pydicom`, a DICOMDIR is represented by a [FileSet](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/tutorials/filesets.html) that handles the specifics of that file type and allows you to search the directory records.
So, if you want to get all DICOM file paths referenced in the DICOMDIR, you can do something like this:

```py
from pydicom import dcmread 
from pydicom.fileset import FileSet

ds = dcmread(dicomdir_path)
fs = FileSet(ds)
root_path = fs.path
# returns all contained values if IMAGE level entries
file_ids = fs.find_values("ReferencedFileID")
for file_id in file_ids:
    # file_id is a list, unpack it into the components using *
    dcm_path = os.path.join(root_path, *file_id)
    print(dcm_path) # here you can collect the paths or load the dataset
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It says name "FileSet" is not defined...

Comment: You have to import it. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Cannot believe that I was stuck for two days because I ignored the import statement in the documentation.... Thank you very much. It is all working.

Comment: Or more simply: `for instance in fs: print(instance.path)`